# Чем можно заменить <br> при переводе страницы на английский?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При переводе с помощью jQuery text() js заменяет слова на нужные, но не учитывает перенос текста, который стоит у меня через <br>.
Чем можно заменить <br> или как передать html-тег <br> с помощью jquery?

```js
var arrLang = {
  "en":{"social":"Vkontakte is the best social network"},
  "ru":{"social":"Вконтакте это самая лучшая социальная сеть"}
}
let select_current = document.querySelector(".select_current");
let sel_body = document.querySelector(".select_body");
let sel_item = document.querySelectorAll(".select_item");
let sel_input = document.querySelector(".select_input");
select_current.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
    sel_body.classList.toggle("is_active");
})
sel_item.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        let elemValue = elem.getAttribute("data-value");
        let elemText = elem.textContent;
        sel_input.value = elemValue;
        select_current.textContent = elemText;
        selectBodyHide();
    })
})

let selectBodyHide = () =>{
    sel_body.classList.remove("is_active");
};
$(function(){
    $(".select_item").click(function(){
        var lang = $(this).attr("data-value");
        $(".lang").each(function(index, element){
            $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
        });
        
    });
});
```

```css
h3{
font-size: 16px;
font-family: "Roboto";
}
.select{
    display: flex;
    font-family: "Circe";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: black;
}
.select_header{
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
.select_current{
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
.select_body{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-top:0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.select_item{
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
}
.select_item:hover, .select_item:focus{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.is_active{
    display:flex;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="lang" key="social">Вконтакте это самая лучшая<br>социальная сеть</h3>
<div class="select">
                <input type="hidden" name="number" class="select_input">
                <div class="select_header">
                    <div class="select_current">Русский</div>
                </div>
                <div class="select_body">
                    <div class="select_item" data-value="en">English</div>
                    <div class="select_item" data-value="ru" >Русский</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: использовать jQuery html(). Или использовать <p>

Answer (score 0):

использовать jQuery html(). Или использовать `<p>`